# How do I save output into a text file in python?

Tags: python, text, output

So what I want to do is save the output of this program into a text file.

```
import itertools
res = itertools.product('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm', repeat=3)
for i in res: 
print ''.join(i)
```

Im running python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `open` and then `write` method of the resulting file handler.

```
import itertools
res = itertools.product('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm', repeat=3)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for group in res:
        word = ''.join(group)
        f.write(word+'\n')
        print(word)
```