# How would I save this output into a text file in python?

Tags: python, output

Im running python 2.7

```
import requests

count = 1000
while count <= 10000:
    count += 1
    user = requests.get("https://api.roblox.com/Users/" + str(count)).json()    ['Username']
    print (user)
```

Thanks!

Comment: fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")
fo.write( user)

Comment: @OmidCompSCI And `fo.close()`

Comment: @Rakesh_K Correct.

Comment: go through this https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: @Rakesh_K> or rather, use `with`, avoiding exception-related issues.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114729/save-a-large-file-using-the-python-requests-library) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126596/saving-response-from-requests-to-file)

Comment: How is this question different from your previous http://stackoverflow.com/q/40558729/2564301?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `open` file, in  `with` statement as this:

```
import requests

count = 1000
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    while count <= 10000:
        count += 1
        user = requests.get("https://api.roblox.com/Users/" + str(count)).json()['Username']
        print (user)
        f.write(user + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's `with`, to open your output file, this way the file is automatically closed afterwards. Secondly, it makes more sense to use `range()` to give you all of your numbers, and `format` can be used to add the number to your URL as follows:

```
import requests

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for count in range(1, 10000 + 1):
        user = requests.get("https://api.roblox.com/Users/{}".format(count)).json()['Username']
        print(user)
        f_output.write(user + '\n')
```

Each entry is then written to the file with a newline after each.